# xclip on headless server

Tags: command-line, server, bash

I've been using xclip to copy the output of bash commands like so:

```
pwd | tr -d "\n" | xclip -selection c
```

So that I can then paste the output into another terminal session.

I was trying to use it on my headless server (ubuntu 13.04), which is started without x. It doesn't work with the error:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

Is there a way around this. I realise that seeing as the program is called xclip it may not be possible.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The clipboard is provided by the [X server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_server). It doesn't matter whether the server is headless or not, what matters is that your local graphical session is available to programs running on the remote machine. Thanks to X's network-transparent design, this is possible.

I assume that you're connecting to the remote server with SSH from a machine running Linux. Make sure that X11 forwarding is enabled both in the client configuration and in the server configuration. In the client configuration, you need to have the line `ForwardX11 yes` in `~/.ssh/config` to have it on by default, or pass the option `-X` to the `ssh` command just for that session. In the server configuration, you need to have the line `X11Forwarding yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (it is present by default on Ubuntu).

To check whether X11 forwarding is enabled, look at the value of the `DISPLAY` environment variable: `echo $DISPLAY`. You should see a value like `localhost:10` (applications running on the remote machine are told to connect to a display running on the same machine, but that display connection is in fact forwarded by SSH to your client-side display). Note that if `DISPLAY` isn't set, it's no use setting it manually: the environment variable is always set correctly if the forwarding is in place. If you need to diagnose SSH connection issues, pass the option `-vvv` to `ssh` to get a detailed trace of what's happening.

If you're connecting through some other means, you may or may not be able to achieve X11 forwarding. If your client is running Windows, [PuTTY](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-x11) supports X11 forwarding; you'll have to run an X server on the Windows machine such as [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/).

Comment: +1 brilliant answer, but as I mentioned this server is running without x so Nykakins answer is more relevant.

Comment: @Anake I'm afraid you misread my answer. A remote display doesn't involve any X server running on the remote machine. You do need to have the `xclip` program installed and the supporting libraries, but that doesn't involve installing an X server.

Comment: Just wondering ... is this approach valid when connecting from an OSX client to a headless Ubuntu server?

Comment: @ken Yes, it's valid when connecting from any machine running an X server to any remote machine where you run an X application. Remember that for X, the server is on the local machine and the client is the application; for the remote protocol, usually the local machine is the client and the remote machine is the server.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm going from mac -> linux server. `X11Forwarding yes` is in the sshd_config on the server and I passed `-X` when I ssh'd to the server. `Error: Can't open display: (null)` on `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | xclip -selection clipboard`

Comment: @chovy You must have an X server running on the client, and you must have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set in the SSH client process. SSH can't forward a connection that it doesn't see.

Comment: ok i figured it would work since `pbcopy` already works on my mac locally. How do I start an x server on a mac and what do I set `$DISPLAY` to?

Comment: @chovy you have to install XQuartz on macOS to enable X Server. (don't forget to log out and log into your mac after installing it).

Answer (score 7):

Bash itself does not have a clipboard. It's a X feature. `xclip` is just a command line interface and as you see, it requires `$DISPLAY`. A way around is to just use a temporary file (for eg created with `tempfile`):

```
$ echo 123 > /tmp/fileDy7Dgv
$ tr -d '2' < /tmp/fileDy7Dgv
13
```

Comment: i don't get it.

Comment: I think you combined two different answers of different post.