# xclip on remote machine

Tags: 16.04, server, clipboard, xclip

I want to paste the contents of my clipboard on machine A (client - Windows 7), to machine B (Ubuntu 16.04 Server). I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305654/xclip-on-headless-server), but I'm still having the same problem. Here is the error message:

```
Error: Clipboard on X11 requires that the DISPLAY envvar be configured.
```

I do have `Xming` installed on my windows machine!

`xclip` is already installed on the Ubuntu server. When I connect to the server via PuTTy, I use the following configuration at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMn6o.png) in my PuTTy config.

What else do I need to be able to paste the clipboard of machine A to B?

The reason my Ubuntu server is a "Shiny" server, and in my "Shiny" app I want to paste data from the clipboard.

Comment: You need X on the local system.

Comment: The error is telling you that you need to set the environment variable DISPLAY so X will know which display to use.  See this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable

Comment: And you have to configure putty so it does X11 Forwarding. That's a client-side action, not a server side one

Comment: @muru I have done it , in putty I enabled  X11 forwarding and set X display location to : `localhost:0.0`, but nothing changed !